# An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Im trying to use here TextFieldProps, but nothing works. Someone know how to deal with this problem? How to use TextFieldProps properly? Thanks for help.

[image]

```
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { colorThemes } from '../../variables/style.variables';

interface BDBTextFieldProps extends TextFieldProps {
  customColor?: string;
}

export const BDBTextField = ({
  customColor = colorThemes.primary,
  ...props
}: BDBTextFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      sx={{
        '& label.Mui-focused': {
          color: customColor,
        },
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
          '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
            borderColor: customColor,
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *@mui/material v5.11.16*
- *TypeScript 5.1.3*

Let's take a look at the `TextFieldProps` type, it's a union type. Source code [TextField.d.ts#L229](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.11.16/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.d.ts#L229)

```
export type TextFieldProps = StandardTextFieldProps | FilledTextFieldProps | OutlinedTextFieldProps;
```

A TS interface is **not allowed to extend a union type.**

```
type U = { a: number } | { b: string };

interface I30 extends U { x: string } // error
```

You can use extend a type via intersections as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)

```
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";

type BDBTextFieldProps = TextFieldProps & {
  customColor?: string;
};

const outlinedProps: BDBTextFieldProps = {
  variant: "outlined",
  customColor: "1"
};
const filledProps: BDBTextFieldProps = {
  variant: "filled",
  customColor: "2"
};
const standardProps: BDBTextFieldProps = {
  variant: "standard",
  customColor: "3"
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-74138466-yxl859?file=/index.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Using an interface does not allow you to extend an object with statically unknown members. Try using type instead.

Comment: You could provide an example of a fix to the error in the screenshot and code provided in the question. To clarify what the materialization of your suggestion is.